# Execute IIS .NET webforms website without precompiling the source code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, vb.net, iis

I want to publish to IIS the source code of my website (visual studio 2017 web forms website in vb.net or c#) without pre-compiling the project, so I can modify the source code directly on the server with IIS.

I know this is possible, I have done it in the past, and I have seen it done even now, but I cannot figure out what I need to do for this.

When I copy all the website source code to the server with the IIS, the website does not run... any ideas? or where to look for an answer? Is it a matter of setup? of the type of project?

When I call the website I get the following error:

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

> Parser Error Message: The CodeDom provider type
>   "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" could not be
>   located.

Source Error:

> An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error
>   settings for this application prevent the details of the application
>   error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could,
>   however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to modify the code directly on the server?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the Website Project as opposed to a Web Application Project that it is probably currently configured as.

Comment: @mason I want to test things on the fly and publishing is a long procedure... its very convenient having the source code on the server at least until the project is settled...

Comment: @Gabe I think you are correct but when I create a new project, I cant see anything like that: Website Project... any idea on exactly what kind of project would behave this way in visual studio 2017? Thanks!

Comment: @Manos, it's a little hidden in newer versions of Visual Studio. When selecting File > New > Project, I see it under Visual Basic/Visual C# > Web > Previous Versions (ASP.NET Web Forms Site)

Comment: @Manos If you want to test things on the fly, I suggest using IIS on your computer.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes of course! but if you have for example mobile devices connecting to handlers, or even running something you want to test with external users, its a hassle... In addition, you could be out of the office and fix things using a remote desktop connection instead of having with you the whole development environment... the bennefits are multiple. thanks!

Comment: @Manos It sounds like testing is not important for your scenario, so why not use RDP to run Visual Studio on the web server - you could compile it directly on the server.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I would never install visual studio on the web server, why add so much unnecessary softtware on the web server? If you can just post the source code and tweek it directly? My development environment has 2 screens, many libraries and tools... I can restart my pc any time I want without disrupting the website etc... I think its obvious why you would never install on a live server visual studio and use it as your main development environment.

Comment: I would never modify source code directly on the server. But if I was going to do so, I’d want to do it in Visual Studio. If your deployment process isn’t working for you, then change that. Don’t lose all the benefits of a proper CI/CD pipeline in your pursuit of this.

Answer (score 0):

@Gabe Thanks for the directions:

> File - New Project, I see it under Visual Basic/Visual C# - Web - Previous Versions (ASP.NET Web Forms Site)

I tried it, and it works just fine! Basically if you create a project like you describe, you can just copy the source code in a server, without even installing visual studio there, and you can develop the site directly there.

This is ideal when you want to test things directly with external users, test things directly on the live or test servers, and of course you can make sure you have the source code of the project running, without having to keep both the source code and the compiled version.

There are a few drawbacks though:
1) you disrupt the website when you change things, and the application pool is restarted whenever there are changes, users in sessions are kicked out, etc...
2) there is a small delay while the site gets recompiled
3) there are cases where if while the code gets recompiled there are users online, there is asp.net corruption

Thanks for the replies!!
Regards
Manos

Comment: If you use out-of-process session state, you can generally avoid the "users in sessions are kicked out" problem.